# .oberve(.childAdded) producing error while .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) is not

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

Right now I have `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` that loads all my annotations onto the map:

```
func loadAnnotations() {

    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for item in snapshot.children {

                // annotationListItem is a struct I created
                let annotationItem = AnnotationListItem(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)

                let doubleLatitude = Double(annotationItem.mapViewLatitude!)
                let doubleLongitude = Double(annotationItem.mapViewLongitude!)
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(doubleLatitude!, doubleLongitude!)

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = coordinate
                annotation.title = annotationItem.annotationTitle
                annotation.subtitle = annotationItem.annotationSubtitle
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        }, withCancel: nil)

    }
}
```

Now I want the map to update every time the user adds a new annotation so I put in the exact same code but with `.observe(.childAdded)`

```
func annotationChildAdded() {

    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            for item in snapshot.children {
                let annotationItem = AnnotationListItem(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)

                let doubleLatitude = Double(annotationItem.mapViewLatitude!)
                let doubleLongitude = Double(annotationItem.mapViewLongitude!)
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(doubleLatitude!, doubleLongitude!)

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = coordinate
                annotation.title = annotationItem.annotationTitle
                annotation.subtitle = annotationItem.annotationSubtitle
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

I get the error of:

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1060b84f0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1060b92d8).
Printing description of snapshotValue:
([String : AnyObject]) snapshotValue = variable not available>

How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

`.observe(.value)` works. But I am still wondering why `.childAdded` doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` and `.observe(.childAdded)` don't return the same thing.

When you call `.observe(.value)` it returns the entire node with all the content inside at the time of the event.

But, when you use `.observe(.childAdded)` it would return only the content that is added to the specified path (that is, the child that is added).

You can see that by doing `print(snapshot)` in both methods and you will easily see the difference.

So, to access your data using .childAdded, you don't need to iterate through all the children like you would do with .observeSingleEvent(of: .value). Instead you would do :

```
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
           return 
        }

        uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                let annotationItem = AnnotationListItem(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)

                let doubleLatitude = Double(annotationItem.mapViewLatitude!)
                let doubleLongitude = Double(annotationItem.mapViewLongitude!)
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(doubleLatitude!, doubleLongitude!)

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = coordinate
                annotation.title = annotationItem.annotationTitle
                annotation.subtitle = annotationItem.annotationSubtitle
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }

        })
```

Also, I would not recommend you to force cast your item like that `item as! DataSnapshot` because if you miss something in your database the app would just crash.

Instead, I would do it like so, using guard statements :

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
     return 
}

uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

        let annotationKey = snapshot.key

        guard let longitude = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as? NSNumber else { return }

        guard let latitude = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as? NSNumber else { return }

        guard let title = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "title").value as? String else { return }

        // Here it really depends on how your database look like.

        // ...

        // Create your annotation item using the values from the snapshot :

        let annotation = AnnotationListItem(id: annotationKey, title: title, longitude: longitue, latitude: latitude)

        // Finally add the data to an array :

        self?.annotationsArray.append(annotation)

        // Or directly to your mapView :

        self?.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

})
```

Just let me know if it helps ;D

**Update**

For example, let's say you have initially 3 child nodes in your database. It would do something like that :

initial :  observer get called :

you get child 1

you get child 2

you get child 3

now, if another child is added :

new child : observer get called :

you get child 4

etc..

Comment: Thank you for this! Just to be clear, I originally thought that `.childAdded` ran through all existing children once and then acted as a listener for every child added. Is that wrong? Secondly, should I call my `loadAnnotations` function in the `viewDidLoad` and then call `annotationChildAdded` right under that?

Comment: You're welcome @zachenn ! You're right, it indeed initially run through all existing children once, and then would trigger for every child added. But in both cases, it would return only that specific child, and not the entire parent node with all its content inside. I updated my answer so that it's easier to understand

Comment: For your second question, I would recommend you to write the child added method in the viewDidAppear method, and make sure you remove all the observers in your viewDidDisappear method. Also, before calling the childAdded observer, you need to remove all the elements that are inside your array to avoid duplicates every time your view controller appears.

Comment: My `AnnotationListItem` is not a MKAnnotation. Is that okay?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your answer, I ended up using `.observeSingleEvent (of: .value)` to initially load the items and then called the updated `.observe (. childAdded)` that you suggested. I also now understand a lot more about guard statements and if let because you brought it up. I appreciate it very much :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad to hear that @zachenn ! Yeah guard statements are really useful and I think they contribute a lot in making the code more elegant :). Have a nice day!

Comment: Hello. I'm doing something similar but once I hit .childAdded my memory spikes. I've tried using [weak self] but I get an error from that. Have any of you encountered this?